# Need help pulling specific type of ID when there are multiple IDs

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a dataset where an employee with one SSN can have multiple employee IDs.  In that situation I need to only brings back records where the employee ID begins with '200.'  In most situations there will only be one employee ID or the employee ID is null(which is okay to bring back).

This is a sample dataset:

```
   declare @t table(id int, name varchar(100), ssn int, eeid int)

   insert into @t
   values(1, 'John Smith', '55512', '2006544'),
   (1, 'John Smith', '55512', '12345'),
   (2, 'Bob Johnson', '55514', '200454'),
   (3, 'Tom Smith', '44454', NULL),
   (4, 'John Thompson', '45434', '204435'),
   (4, 'John Thompson', '45434', '12353568')
```

The output should look like this:

```
   Id      Name       SSN        EEID
   1     John Smith     55512      2006544
   2     Bob Johnson    55514      200454
   3     Tom Smith      44454      NULL
   4     John Thompson  45434      204435
```

I tried playing with a Window function but got stuck.  I tried using Rownum but it didn't give the correct result with 'John Smith.'

```
   select *,
   row_number()over(partition by ssn ORDER BY case when EEID like '200%' 
   then 1 end) AS ROWNUM
   from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER`, on it's own, doesn't change the returned rows, it just "numbers" them. You'd either need to put the expression in a CTE/Subquery and then filter to the first row in the `WHERE`, or you use `TOP` and put the expression in the `ORDER BY`:

```sql
--CTE solution
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           [Name],
           SSN,
           EEID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SSD ORDER BY CASE WHEN eeid LIKE '200%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, eeid ASC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT ID,
       [Name],
       SSN,
       EEID
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;

--ORDER BY and TOP solution
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       ID,
       [Name],
       SSN,
       EEID
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SSD ORDER BY CASE WHEN eeid LIKE '200%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, eeid);
```